# freebsd: Illegal variable name

Tags: curl, freebsd, csh

I am trying to run the following command:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

but getting:

```
Illegal variable name.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Appears to work fine under Ubuntu 20 (under WSL). Make sure `sh` is running the correct shell. FreeBSD does not use `bash` as default. "Illegal variable name" is a common `csh` error for things like `$?`.

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes around the expression.

Comment: I don't think (t)csh supports `$()`.

Comment: In FreeBSD, `sh` is not bash and bash is not installed by default but you have this tagged as bash. Are you really running bash?

Comment: You are clearly using `sh` here; why is this tagged [tag:csh]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First never run script downloaded like that. You never know what it is going to execute on your system.

- First download the script with:
  `curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh`
- Then run the script with ksh or bash:
  `bash install.sh`

I checked this install script code and it is not passing shellcheck.net static analysis. So its authors have more homework to do.

Comment: The actual problem the author is running in to is that tcsh doesn't know about `"$(...)"`, and that this gets interpreted as an (invalid) variable since they're using double quotes. Replacing it with `'` should fix it. Just FYI.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I have the feeling that replacing `$(command)` with backtick, may not help much, as the whole installer script requires a POSIX shell to run.

Comment: @MartinTournoij no it doesnt work with `'`

Answer (score 0):

Check the shell that is default on your FreeBSD:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # echo "$SHELL"
/bin/csh
```

If it is `csh` (C shell), variables should be set this way:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # set test=`echo "hello"`
root@freebsd-13:~ # echo "$test"
hello
```

The following example won't work:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # set test="$(echo "hello")"
Illegal variable name.
```

But you can set it with `sh` this way:

```
root@freebsd-13:~ # sh
# test="$(echo "hello")"
# echo $test
hello
#
```